# Iterating through a list in each row of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

I pulled an IMDB dataset down from [Kraggle](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset#IMDb%20ratings.csv). I am merging two of the files together and am wanting to explore ratings by genre. The genre cell contains all genre keywords for the row. I have created a new column for each genre (i.e. horror, drama, comedy, etc.) and would like to put an "x" in each row where the genre matches the appropriate column.
I have tried to split the genre column and then iterate through each row, placing an 'x' in the appropriate corresponding column, but I cant seem to get it to function properly.  Either there will be an 'x' in every column on every row, or I get an "x" for the very first genre listed for each row. Blow is an image of how the cell reads.

[image: Genre Column structure]

This is what I am currently attempting.

```py
    movies = pd.read_csv('IMDb movies.csv')
    ratings = pd.read_csv('IMDb ratings.csv')
    imdb = pd.merge(movies, ratings , on=['imdb_title_id'], how='inner')

    def genre_fill(n):
        list = imdb.genre.str.split(',')
        for i in list: 

            if n == 'Western':
                imdb['Western'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Drama':
                imdb[ 'Drama'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Fantasy':
                imdb['Fantasy'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Comedy':
                imdb['Comedy'] = 'x' 
            if n == 'Action':
                imdb['Action'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Adventure':
                imdb['Adventure'] = 'x' 
            if n == 'Biography':
                imdb['Biography'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Romance':
                imdb['Romance'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Mystery':
                imdb['Mystery'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Crime':
                imdb['Crime'] = 'x' 
            if n == 'Film-Noir':
                imdb['Film-Noir'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Music':
                imdb['Music'] = 'x' 
            if n == 'Horror':
                imdb['Horror'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Musical':
                imdb['Musical'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Thriller':
                imdb['Thriller'] = 'x'
            if n == 'War':
                imdb['War'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Sci-Fi':
                imdb['Sci-Fi'] = 'x'
            if n == 'Sport':
                imdb['Sport'] = 'x' 
            if n == 'Family':
                imdb['Family'] = 'x'
            if n == 'History':
                imdb['History'] = 'x' 



    for value in imdb['genre']:
        genre_fill(value)
```

This is my first python project. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way, I hope it helps.
First, extract all your genres from the `genre` column.

```
cols = set([i.split(',')[0] for i in df.genre.tolist()])
print(cols)
```

`cols` will look like this:

```
{'Action',
 'Adult',
 'Adventure',
 'Animation',
 'Biography',
 'Comedy',
 'Crime',
 'Documentary',
 'Drama',
 'Family',
 'Fantasy',
 'Film-Noir',
 'History',
 'Horror',
 'Music',
 'Musical',
 'Mystery',
 'Romance',
 'Sci-Fi',
 'Sport',
 'Thriller',
 'War',
 'Western'}
```

Create columns in the df:

```
for c in cols:
    df[c] = 0
```

Fill the values:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for g in row['genre'].split(', '):
            df.at[index,g] = 1
```

This code will make a column for each genre and fill the values with 1.
This is not the best approach as I am using loops. But for this dataset is not that bad!

The result will be something like this:

```
   id Drama War Animation ...
    0   1    0     0      ...
    1   0    1     1      ...
```

please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks That got me farther than I was. The result is only populating the first genre listed. It does not seem to iterate through each one. So, if film is a Drama, Comedy. The result will place a '1' in Drama and Comedy remains a '0'. Any thoughts?

Comment: add a space after ',' in `for g in row['genre'].split(',')`. so it should be `for g in row['genre'].split(', ')`. it should work now

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
def genre_fill(n):
        list = n.str.split(',')
        for i in list: 

            if i == 'Western':
                imdb['Western'] = 'x'
            if i == 'Drama':
                imdb[ 'Drama'] = 'x'
            #etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best aproach is not to put an "x" or any letter, it's to put 1 or 0. It would be easier to do some calculations later.

That said, I would do the following (for this, you need to import the numpy library the same way you import "pandas" --> import numpy as np):

1. Make a set (so you don´t get repeated values) of all the genders

`genre_list = {i.strip() for i in np.hstack(df['genre'].map(lambda x: x.split(',')))}`

2. Create one column for each genre where you put 1 if the gender appears on that row or 0 if it doesn't. The 'find' method returns -1 if the string doesn´t exists inside the text I'm looking

`for i in genre_list:
        df[i] = df['genre'].map(lambda x: 1 if x.find(i) > 0 else 0)`

I hope it was useful, let me know if it works.